# How to get a circle over A

Tags: accents, characters

As given on [this](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/LaTeX_symbols.pdf) website, the command `\AA` is what I am looking for. However it simply produces `rA` instead of putting a circle over the top vertex of A. How do I fix this? I am trying to get someone's name right in the bibliography.

The following is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=A4, fontsize=12, toc=listof, toc=bib]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm, outer=2cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{natmove}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[hypcap]{caption}
\usepackage[perpage, symbol*]{footmisc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[hidelinks, breaklinks]{hyperref}

    \makeatletter
\def\NAT@spacechar{}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\setcitestyle{comma}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]%
    {\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]%
    {\markright{\small\thesection\ #1}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\small\thepage}]%
    {\fancyplain{}{\small\rightmark}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\small\leftmark}]%
    {\fancyplain{}{\small\thepage}}
\cfoot{}

%\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
%    \vspace*{-3pt}%
%    \noindent\rule{\columnwidth}{0.4pt}%
%    \vspace*{2.6pt}%
%}

% % Math abbreviations start

\newcommand{\gLL}{\left|\bar{\gamma}\right|}
\newcommand{\gG}{\left|\gamma\right|}

\newcommand{\muB}{\mu_{\text{B}}}

\newcommand{\Ga}{\Gamma}

\newcommand{\B}{\mathbf{B}}

\newcommand{\D}{\overleftrightarrow{\mathbf{D}}}

\renewcommand{\H}{\mathbf{H}}
\newcommand{\Heff}{\H_{\text{eff}}}
\newcommand{\Hext}{\H_{\text{ext}}}
\newcommand{\Hexch}{\H_{\text{exch}}}
\newcommand{\Hdem}{\H_{\text{dem}}}
\newcommand{\Hanis}{\H_{\text{anis}}}
\newcommand{\Hbias}{\H_{\text{bias}}}
\newcommand{\Hsig}{\H_{\text{sig}}}

\newcommand{\I}{\mathbf{I}}

\newcommand{\J}{\mathbf{J}}

\newcommand{\M}{\mathbf{M}}
\newcommand{\Ms}{M_{\text{s}}}
\newcommand{\Mrf}{\tilde{m}({\bf r}, f)}
\newcommand{\Mrfv}{\left|\Mrf\right|}
\newcommand{\Mrfb}{\left(\Mrf\right)}

\newcommand{\X}{{\rm X}}
\newcommand{\Y}{{\rm Y}}
\newcommand{\Mp}{{\rm M}}

\newcommand{\N}{\overleftrightarrow{\mathbf{N}}}

\newcommand{\Py}{Ni$_{80}$Fe$_{20}$}

\newcommand{\fex}{f_{\text{ex}}}

\renewcommand{\k}{\mathbf{k}}
\newcommand{\kB}{k_{\text{B}}}

\newcommand{\lex}{\lambda_{\text{ex}}}

\newcommand{\mB}{\mu_{\text{B}}}

\newcommand{\m}{\mathbf{m}}

\newcommand{\mean}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}

\newcommand{\ms}[1][r]{\mean{{#1}^2}}

\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}

\renewcommand{\r}{\mathbf{r}}
\newcommand{\ri}{\r_i}
\newcommand{\rj}{\r_j}
\newcommand{\br}{\left( \r \right)}
\newcommand{\bri}{\left( \ri \right)}
\newcommand{\brj}{\left( \rj \right)}
\newcommand{\bridrj}{\left( \ri - \rj \right)}
\newcommand{\brt}[1]{\left( \r, t_{#1} \right)}
\newcommand{\hrt}[1]{\mathbf{h} \left( \M, \r, t_{#1} \right)}

\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}

\newcommand{\tc}[1]{\textcircled{\scriptsize #1}}
%4-1 = \tc{1}
%4-6 = \tc{2}
%3-3 = \tc{3}
%3-6 = \tc{4}

\newcommand{\se}{\mathbf{s}}
\newcommand{\bse}{\left( \se \right)}

\newcommand{\citesource}[1]{Source: Ref.$\:$\citenum{#1}}

\newcommand{\tens}[1]{\overleftrightarrow{\mathbf{#1}}}

\newcommand{\unit}[1]{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc}


% % Math abbreviations end

%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\sectfont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
%\setkomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\def\chapterautorefname{Chap.}
\def\sectionautorefname{Sec.}
\def\subsectionautorefname{sub--Sec.}
\def\figureautorefname{Fig.}
\def\tableautorefname{Tab.}
\def\equationautorefname~#1\null{Eq.~(#1)\null}

\def\AAo{\textrm{A\kern -1.3ex\raisebox{0.6ex}{$^\circ$}}}

\newcommand{\Autoref}[1]{\begingroup\def\chapterautorefname{Chapter}\def\sectionautorefname{Section}\def\subsectionautorefname{Sub--Section}\def\figureautorefname{Figure}\def\tableautorefname{Table}\def\equationautorefname~##1\null{Equation~(##1)\null}\autoref{#1}\endgroup}

\begin{document}
Cited here \cite{Bonetti2009}.

\begin{thebibliography}{349}%
\makeatletter
\providecommand \@ifxundefined [1]{%
 \@ifx{#1\undefined}
}%
\providecommand \@ifnum [1]{%
 \ifnum #1\expandafter \@firstoftwo
 \else \expandafter \@secondoftwo
 \fi
}%
\providecommand \@ifx [1]{%
 \ifx #1\expandafter \@firstoftwo
 \else \expandafter \@secondoftwo
 \fi
}%
\providecommand \natexlab [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \enquote  [1]{``#1''}%
\providecommand \bibnamefont  [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \bibfnamefont [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \citenamefont [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \href@noop [0]{\@secondoftwo}%
\providecommand \href [0]{\begingroup \@sanitize@url \@href}%
\providecommand \@href[1]{\@@startlink{#1}\@@href}%
\providecommand \@@href[1]{\endgroup#1\@@endlink}%
\providecommand \@sanitize@url [0]{\catcode `\\12\catcode `\$12\catcode
  `\&12\catcode `\#12\catcode `\^12\catcode `\_12\catcode `\%12\relax}%
\providecommand \@@startlink[1]{}%
\providecommand \@@endlink[0]{}%
\providecommand \url  [0]{\begingroup\@sanitize@url \@url }%
\providecommand \@url [1]{\endgroup\@href {#1}{\urlprefix }}%
\providecommand \urlprefix  [0]{URL }%
\providecommand \Eprint [0]{\href }%
\providecommand \doibase [0]{http://dx.doi.org/}%
\providecommand \selectlanguage [0]{\@gobble}%
\providecommand \bibinfo  [0]{\@secondoftwo}%
\providecommand \bibfield  [0]{\@secondoftwo}%
\providecommand \translation [1]{[#1]}%
\providecommand \BibitemOpen [0]{}%
\providecommand \bibitemStop [0]{}%
\providecommand \bibitemNoStop [0]{.\EOS\space}%
\providecommand \EOS [0]{\spacefactor3000\relax}%
\providecommand \BibitemShut  [1]{\csname bibitem#1\endcsname}%
\let\auto@bib@innerbib\@empty

\bibitem [{\citenamefont {Bonetti}\ \emph {et~al.}(2009)\citenamefont
  {Bonetti}, \citenamefont {Muduli}, \citenamefont {Mancoff},\ and\
  \citenamefont {\AAo~kerman}}]{Bonetti2009}%
  \BibitemOpen
  \bibfield  {author} {\bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {S.}~\bibnamefont
  {Bonetti}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {P.}~\bibnamefont {Muduli}},
  \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {F.}~\bibnamefont {Mancoff}}, \ and\
  \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {J.}~\bibnamefont {\AAo~kerman}},\ }\href
  {\doibase http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.3097238} {\bibfield  {journal}
  {\bibinfo  {journal} {Appl. Phys. Lett.}\ }\textbf {\bibinfo {volume} {94}},\
  \bibinfo {eid} {102507} (\bibinfo {year} {2009})}\BibitemShut {NoStop}%

\end{thebibliography}%

\end{document}
```

The above example spits out these errors:

```
Use of \@item doesn't match its definition ...itenamefont {\AAo~kerman}}]{Bonetti2009}
Argument of \@rsbox has an extra } ...itenamefont {\AAo~kerman}}]{Bonetti2009}
Paragraph ended before \@rsbox was complete ...itenamefont {\AAo~kerman}}]{Bonetti2009}
Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 1076 ...itenamefont {\AAo~kerman}}]{Bonetti2009}
Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write ...itenamefont {\AAo~kerman}}]{Bonetti2009}
```

The bibliography part was auto-generated using BibTeX. Changing `\AAo~` to `{\AAo}` fixes the problem. But I would rather have it done automatically. Also getting `\AA{}` to work on its own will be even better.

Comment: What about something like `\def\AA{\textrm{A\kern -1.3ex\raisebox{0.6ex}{$^\circ$}}}`?

Comment: `\AA` works properly on my system with your preamble. If you provide a complete MWE we might be of more help. Also, try to reduce the packages to the minimum set required to produce the error. This not only might help you find the source of the error on your own, but also will help the community help you quickly. `:-)`

Comment: Query edited as per the request.

Comment: I started with your MWE and converted all `\AAo` to `\AA` and it works. Not sure what's going on with your setup.

Comment: You end your posting by saying that "Also getting \AA{} to work on its own will be even better." On my system (MacTeX2013 & pdfLaTeX, all updates applied), your code runs just fine if I replace `\AAo~` with `\AA{}`. Which TeX distribution and which TeX engine/format do you use?

Comment: @Mico `\AA{}kerman` wouldn't apply kerning; probably not really important in this particular case.

Comment: BTW you link to an old version of the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbols](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), which is also included in teX distributions.

Comment: I am using MiKTeX 2.9.4196 with TexStudio 2.6.6. I use the dvi->ps->pdf chain. Using pdflatex creates a file size over the acceptable limit.

Comment: Updated the MWE to include all the code that I am using. Perhaps something there is causing the malfunction.

Comment: Thanks for posting a working example. You mention that the problem code is actually generated during a BibTeX run. Please also post the full bib entry -- or at least its `author` field. The ideal place to fix the problem is at the source, not downstream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't redefine `\r` as this is the 'ring' used over 'å'.